# While using reindex method on any dataframe why do original values go missing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-indexing-techniques

This is the original Dataframe: 
[image]
**What I wanted :** I wanted to convert this above data-frame into this multi-indexed column data-frame :
[image]
I managed to do it by this piece of code :

```
# tols : original dataframe
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],['Y','X'] 
['P','Q']])
tols.set_axis(cols, axis = 1, inplace = False)
```

**What I tried :** I tried to do this with the `reindex` method like this :

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],['Y','X'], 
['P','Q']])
tols.reindex(cols, axis = 'columns')
```

it resulted in an output like this : 
[image]

**My problem :**
As you could see in the output above all my original numerical values go missing on employing the `reindex` method. In the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) page it was clearly mentioned :
*Conform DataFrame to new index with optional filling logic, placing NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index. A new object is produced unless the new index is equivalent to the current one.* So i don't understand:

- Where did i particularly err in employing the `reindex` method to lose my original values
- How should i have employed the `reindex` method correctly to get my desired output

Comment: Has this question been sufficiently answered?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your code the `tols` must be `cols`?

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],['Y','X'] 
['P','Q']])
tols.set_axis(cols, axis = 1, inplace = False)
```

This must be:

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],['Y','X'] 
['P','Q']])
cols.set_axis(cols, axis = 1, inplace = False)
```

Personally I would have removed nan with a default value before performing the multi-indexing.

```
df_noNAN = from_product.fillna(value=-1)
```

In your case it looks like the inplace is producing a bug and better reported to the pandas team. On Stack exchange they are extremely responsive.

Comment: `cols` is the multindex formed right ?....so I am applying this multindex `cols`  to my original data frame `tols`...

Comment: Okay, yes I misread your code ... although you didn't mention the 'tols' dataframe. Anyway same idea "fillna" I my opinion would be a standard approach prior further manipulation.